# Kotlin behaves weird in identity of boxed and unboxed numbers

Tags: android, kotlin

In my algorithm, I have been checking identify of the int variable and   nullable int,

```
var literal_num: Int = 1000

var literal_num_boxed: Int? = literal_num

println("***********************************")

println((literal_num === literal_num_boxed)) //print false

println("***********************************")
```

but when you change the number to 100 the identity is equal, am i doing wrong here?

```
var literal_num: Int = 100

var literal_num_boxed: Int? = literal_num

println("***********************************")

println((literal_num === literal_num_boxed)) //true

println("***********************************")
```

---

I tried the same in the kotlin documentation. its also behaving the same. check the following images.

---

[image]

---

After i edited the number to 100 it behaves the in a different way.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Integer.valueOf` has caches.

When you use `===` to compare int and Int?, autobox happens and it calls `Integer.valueOf`.

```
    public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
        if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
            return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
        return new Integer(i);
    }
```

From `Integer.java`. `low` is -128 and `high` is 127 by default.

When autobox happens, every number from -128 to 127 will share a same `Integer` and your result will be true. If a number isn't in that range, a new `Integer` will be created and your result will be false.

Related design patterns: https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/flyweight/